# Unable to hide element inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm using Joomla framework. I created a system plugin which should load on every page. When I navigate to a particular component, I see my plugin icon appears t bottom of the document which is correct.

When I click to load the `iframe`, which shows the entire document in it, I hide my plugin which is outside the `iframe` like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '[data-eb-composer]', function() {

     //hide the plugin icon
    $('.btn-toggle-ckit').hide();
});
```

Unfortunately this doesn't hide the plugin loaded inside `iframe`. Though I tried the same method to hide, it doesn't work. Basically two icons of my plugin  loaded when iframe loaded, on outside of it and the other inside it.

```
$('.iframe-composer').contents().find('.btn-toggle-ckit').hide();
```

How do I hide my plugin icon from `iframe`?

tried but not working:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".iframe-composer").contents().find('.btn-toggle-ckit').hide();   
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `display:none` on the other page where `.btn-toggle-ckit` resides in?

Comment: @zer00ne, the one inside iframe still shows up

Comment: If you control the other page, you should be able to add this `<style>.btn-toggle-ckit {display:none;}</style>` or `opacity: 0`, or `visibility: hidden`. To *that page* which is in the iframe, *not the page* that hosts the iframe.

Comment: @zer00ne, both are on the same page..I'm able to hide the one outside iframe but not the one inside of it

Comment: An iframe is an element displays an entirely different web page like a window of a room (i.e. main page) with a view of another room (i.e. the page inside the iframe). If something is within an iframe, that would mean that that something is in another webpage, therefore both could not be on the same page.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/pLNS7tkgvorkzFsevRBv/

Comment: @zer00ne, I understood now.. I could not hardcode to hide the element inside the iframe page. Somehow I need to find some other way where the plugin will not load or something when iframe is loaded.

Comment: Do you control page in the iframe? If not, then it's not possible for you to change anything within the iframe due to security precautions the browser implements. I'm not knowledgeable with Joomla, but I'm familiar enough to recall that CMSs are terribly limiting with iframes.

Comment: @zer00ne, I've no idea why it doesn't hide at all..I've tried all the solutions suggested... Please see my post, added an image of DOM struture...

Comment: Do you know how to access and edit `index.php` from the admin panel? If so, the button can be styled inline (ex. 1.`<div id="ckit" ....style="display:none">` or by a 2.`<style>` block, or if there's a 3.`<link>` then you can modify the `filename.css`. I'm not sure about 2. and 3. since I don't know PHP that well let alone Joomla, plus the image doesn't show the contents of `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

What about binding on frame load in addition to dom load?

```
 $(function() {
    var frame = $(".iframe-composer");
    frame.load(function() {
        frame.contents().find('.btn-toggle-ckit').hide();
    });
 })
```

Comment: I added an image of DOM structure, please see if you notice the problm

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the DOM element, when you run this in developer console  $(".iframe-composer").contents().find('.btn-toggle-ckit')

try $('#idaboveIframe").contents().find('iframe').contents().find('.btn-toggle-ckit').hide()